# I would like a vertical (feedback) button to have a slight animated slideout effect on mouse over

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Here is an example of what I want to achieve - http://home.mcafee.com/default.aspx

I would like to know how to get the feedback tab/button to the right of the page to slightly open not completely slide out. And then on clicking, I would like to open a page (not a jquery form, but a page).

Any help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try the updated fiddle in answer. Hope you want this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS3 transitions

```
#feedback {
     transition:width 1s;
     -moz-transition:width 1s; /* Firefox 4 */
     -webkit-transition:width 1s; /* Safari and Chrome */
     -o-transition:width 1s; /* Opera */
     background:#ccc url(http://home.mcafee.com/OpinionLab/img/oo_tab_icon.gif) no-repeat 50% 90%;
     position:fixed;
     width:30px;
     height:100px;
     border:solid #666 1px;
     right:-10px;
     top:30%;
     padding:0px 5px 5px 0px;
}

#feedback:hover
{
     width:50px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this http://jsfiddle.net/heera/q5Nu2/5 and you have to use a background image to show a vertical button.

**CSS**

```
#feedback{
background:#ccc url(http://home.mcafee.com/OpinionLab/img/oo_tab_icon.gif) no-repeat 50% 90%;
position:fixed;
width:30px;
height:100px;
border:solid #666 1px;
right:-10px;
top:30%;
padding:0px 5px 5px 0px;
}

#feedback img{width:100%;height:70px;border:solid black 1px;}​
```

**HTML**

```
<a href="page_url" id="feedback"></a>​
```

**JS**

```
$('a#feedback').hover(function(e){
    $(this).animate({'right':'-1px'}, 500);
},
function(e){
    $(this).animate({'right':'-10px'}, 500);
});​
```

Comment: I know how to get the vertical tab/button. I was looking for the animation effect on it as shown in the url I provided in my question.

Comment: If you meant the animated +/- sign bottom of the Feedback then it's a gif image here http://home.mcafee.com/OpinionLab/img/oo_tab_icon.gif

Comment: No, I meant how the button comes out a little on mouse over. I think thats done with CSS.

Comment: Got it, Are you using jquery ?